# Self Made Tkinter Popup Menu Python

Tags: python, events, tkinter, popup

I was writing a GUI library in Python based on tkinter and I was designing and building all the widgets, but I have come to the PopUp menus.
Due that tkinter picks system menus and this can't be customized, I write the following code to make a frame where I can put my customized buttons in and works as a popup.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

w = Label(root, text="Right-click to display menu", width=40, height=20)
w.place(x=0)


def function1():
    print('function1 activated')
# create a menu
f = Frame(root,width=80,height=60,background='green')
b2 = Button(f,text='function',command=function1)
b2.pack()

def open_popup(event):
    try:
        f.place(x=event.x, y=event.y)
        root.after(1)
        f.focus_set()
        w.bind_all("<Button-1>",close_popup)
    except:
        print("Can't open popup menu")

def close_popup(event):
    try:
        f.place_forget()
        root.after(1)
        w.unbind_all("<Button-1>")
    except:
        print("Can't close popup menu")

w.bind("<Button-3>", open_popup)

b = Button(root, text="Quit", command=root.destroy)
b.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Everything works well, if I clicked with the mouse right-button the popup menu appears, and if I clicked on every other part the popup menu dissapears.
The problem is that, due to `bind_all` when I press the button of my popup menu, `function1` doesn't run and the event handler closes the popup. I have tried with only  `bind` but this time, `function1` runs and the event handler doesn't activates.

Is there anyway I can do that?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would do this using a tracking variable.

We can first assign `None` to `f` as a way to check if `f` is currently set up.

If `f` is not None then we create frame and button. Then when the function is activated we can run function and destroy the frame the button was in. This also destroys the button and then we set `f` back to `None` for out next use.

Take a look at the below reworked example.
Let me know if you have any questions.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

w = Label(root, text="Right-click to display menu", width=40, height=20)
w.place(x=0)
f = None # Tracking F to see if it is None or not.

def function1():
    global f
    print('function1 activated')
    # add this to the end of the function to destroy the frame and reset f
    if f != None:
        f.destroy()
        f = None

def open_popup(event):
    global f
    # if f is None then create frame and button else don't
    if f == None:
        f = Frame(root,width=80,height=60,background='green')
        f.place(x=event.x, y=event.y)
        b2 = Button(f,text='function',command=function1)
        b2.pack()
    else:
        print("Can't open popup menu")


w.bind("<Button-3>", open_popup)
b = Button(root, text="Quit", command=root.destroy)
b.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I have tried a very similar way before, but the popup menu doesn't dissapear when I clicked in another place, it only disappears when the button of the frame `f` is clicked, so I have the same problem of binding the `close_popup` event handler.

Comment: Ok, so I resolve myself the problem with a little trick. I will post a response.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do this without modifying so much the code, the idea of the tracking variable was good but doesn't solve all the problems, and this code does.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

w = Label(root, text="Right-click to display menu", width=40, height=20)
w.pack()


def function1():
    print('function1 activated')
    try:
        f.place_forget()
    except:
        pass
# create a menu
f = Frame(root,width=80,height=60,background='green')
b2 = Button(f,text='function',command=function1)
b2.place(x=0,y=5)

def open_popup(event): 
    try:
        f.place(x=event.x, y=event.y)
        root.after(1)
        f.focus_set()
    except:
        pass

def close_popup(event):
    try:
        f.place_forget()
        root.after(1)
        w.unbind_all("<Button-1>")
    except:
        pass

def enable_depopup(event):
    w.bind_all("<Button-1>",close_popup)

def disable_depopup(event):
    w.unbind_all("<Button-1>")

w.bind("<Button-3>", open_popup)
w.bind("<Motion>", enable_depopup)
f.bind("<Motion>", disable_depopup)

b = Button(root, text="Quit", command=root.destroy)
b.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

In this way, everytime I move the mouse over the parent window, the `<Button-1>` of the mouse is binded to close the popup menu.
And doing a trick, that is place the button of the menu a few pixels down, this let the mouse pass through the popup frame to reach the button and disable the `<Button-1>` binding letting me click the button.
The function of the button activate the `place_forget` method of the frame, so everything works correctly.